# Rails new_record? method inside transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, transactions

I have a form object, which have difficult structure - in general, it's wrapped in the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  task = Task.create(valid_params)
  puts task # => Task id: 1, title: 'abc'... id is present, so, the task in the database
  do_something unless task.new_record? # do something if the task in the database
end
```

It seems strange, but because of [transaction wasn't ended](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/93a6500baa6bbb331bb93ccdc14fdda5769f5ef9/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L85), `new_record?` returns true (but `task` is *ready* to be stored at the database). Is there any way to check persistence inside the transaction block? I have in mind just dirty `id.present?` & `valid?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was wrong because of `new_record?` & `persisted?` works well inside transaction